# Running PlayWright for python running on google cloud app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, playwright-python

Hello PlayWright has the setup command `playwright install` that needs to be run before it can be used. How could I setup a install script on GCP,s app engine to run this command before running my Django app?

Answer (score 0):

You can install your `playwright` by adding it in `requirement.txt`. Once you re-deploy, it will be installed automatically together with your app.

example in **`requirement.txt`**:

```
playwright==1.9.2
```

But if it needs another command for installment, you should use App Engine Flexible. In App Engine Flexible, you can use Dockerfile to run another command and other configuration to install your additional dependencies and applications.

Comment: I do not think that fixes the problem.
On the playwright website's, it says to run `pip install playwright`  then `playwright install`. How do I run the `playwright install` part on google app engine?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but resolved with some iteration. You can follow these steps:

Having added playwright and version into requirements.txt, in the main script use the subprocess module

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["playwright", "install"])
```

This will help install the browsers

Comment: I resolved it by switch to puppeteer and creating a new service. Then sending request to the puppeteer service via api calls